# Alternative ways to get a full path of a file

Tags: .net, path, relative-path

Is there any alternative way to get a full path of a file without using Path.GetFullPath method?

Comment: You forgot to tell the programming language in question.

Comment: It's probably .NET. However, why can't you use `Path.GetFullPath`?

Comment: I need to create a file whose directory exceeds 248 characters. Hence trying to append (relative) path to \\?\ as mentioned in MSDN.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx#win32__file_namespaces

It appears that I should pass fully qualified path instead of relative path. If I use Path.GetFullPath, it throws PathTooLongException (directory exceeds 248 chars). Is there any equivalent Win32 API to get the full path?

Answer (score 0):

Check [BCL Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2007/02/13/long-paths-in-net-part-1-of-3-kim-hamilton.aspx)

There are links to parts 2 and 3

Answer (score 0):

Able to resolve it using GetFullPathName function.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364963%28VS.85%29.aspx

Thanks